# How to set document height on mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, mobile-safari

We are using a burger menu, that floats from the left side. As the page is long and the menu is short, it was decided to set document height to equal the menu height. We are using jQuery, so it's a pretty simple code line:

```
$(document).height( 1025 ); // the number is just an example
```

Anyway, this works as a charm in FF, Chrome on desktop and also in Chrome devise emulator, but just fails on mobile Safari (testing on an iPad with iOS8).

When trying to check the document height after it was set to desired value, it's just not changed:

```
alert($(document).height());
```

This gives: 1025 on desktop browsers and 3000+ on mobile Safari.

So the question is - does anyone know how to fix this - e.g. how to set `$(document)` height on mobile Safari?

Comment: Document or window height O.o

Comment: Doesn't really matter. All I want is that the content will not be displayed after 1025px from the top of the document, e.g. it should be hidden like when using `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's bug in Safari. You may try to detect exactly this version of Safari:

```
navigator.userAgent.match
```

After this add special class to body element if "match" equals to the broken Safari:

> $('body').AddClass('safarifix');

When this is done, try to add some sort of CSS to `<head></head>` of your web page:

```
.safarifix { height: 1025px; }
```

Good luck!